# Ubuntu 20.04 split second freeze every ten seconds

Tags: 20.04

I've had 20.04 running on my Dell Inspiron 5755 laptop for several weeks now, but in the last few days have noticed a split second freeze pretty much exactly every 10 seconds. This is most noticeable watching videos on youtube, for instance, but also when simply scrolling a screen. The system monitor will show Firefox at the top of the process list, but after a freeze, gnome-shell jumps to the top. Processor: AMD A8-7410 apu with amd radeon r5 graphics × 4; Graphics: AMD Kabini. I've found other freeze related questions, but none that quite match my experience. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the RiseUp VPN client was the cause of the freezes. I was playing with minimizing the number of snaps on my system and all came right when it was removed.